# PHP Not Executable in Command Prompt Windows, Environment Variable is set

Tags: php, windows, path, environment-variables, settings

I'm trying to install PHP and get the error

> 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

I have specified the path `C:\php` in my environment variable tho but I still get the error. Does anybody know what is wrong?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to reopen terminal ? Are you sure that your php folder contains php cli file ?

Comment: I think php executable is under php-7 folder, try adding that folder also like C:/php/php-7.1.3 in environment variable

Comment: I don't see any cli file and also i tried to change it c:\php\php-7.1.3 but it still not working...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you install WAMPP, and in the environment variable, set the correct location of the installed php version, and set it for the user, if after performing the procedure, try to log the user out of windows and log in again.